# Switching around elements in an array based on calculations (in a nested for loop?)

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, nested

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so forgive any formatting mistakes.

I have a project named BOGOTotal - basically, its job is to take a decimal array of prices, sort them in ascending order, and then determine which prices will be bought and which prices will be free. Anyways, that's just a bit of backstory, but I need something more specific.

I've got two arrays - one  of the prices, and one of the quantities of those prices. For example, in my Items array (should have been named "prices"), Items[0] is set to 2.20m, and my Quantities array, Quantites[0] is set to 5. Meaning I have five of the same item that are priced at $2.20.

```
        //create items array
        decimal[] Items = new decimal[5];
        Items[0] = 2.20m;
        Items[1] = 1.50m;
        Items[2] = 8.40m;
        Items[3] = 4.60m;
        Items[4] = 3.75m;

        //create quantity array
        int[] Quantity = new int[Items.Length];
        Quantity[0] = 5;
        Quantity[1] = 2;
        Quantity[2] = 1;
        Quantity[3] = 3;
        Quantity[4] = 6;
```

I then had to sort the Items array in ascending order.

```
        Array.Sort(Items);
```

However, when I sorted my Items array, the relation of each item to its quantity is now lost, because Items[0] and Quantity[0] no longer are related. Now, instead of Items[0] = 2.20m, it has become Items[0] = 1.50m. Now, I have 5 items that are $1.50 instead of $2.20.

Here's where I had my idea - I would go ahead and calculate the prices of the old arrays by creating a firstPrices array, putting them in a for loop, and saying

```
        decimal[] firstPrices = new decimal[Items.Length];

        //calculate prices before sorting - will match back up afterward
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
        {
            firstPrices[i] = Items[i] * Convert.ToDecimal(Quantity[i]);
        }
```

Here comes the hard part: I'm trying to re-align (for lack of a better word) each quantity to its Item - meaning I'm trying to make the item that is $2.20 match back up with its correct quantity (being 5). However, I'm having a hard time doing this. I tried a nested for loop within another for loop that tested each quantity by multiplying it by the current Item and then comparing it to that spot in firstPrices:

```
        //i would be newItems
        //j would be quantity
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Items.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Items[i] * Quantity[j] == firstPrices[i])
                {
                    Quantity[i] = Quantity[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

When it found a match, I set it to break out of the nested loop and increment "i", which goes to the next item in the Items array. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you allowed to create `struct` s or `class`es, or even `Tuple`s?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to initialize the values in your 2 arrays in order. I can't give you code because I don't know C# but for the logic:

make a copy of your prices array, say pricesUnordered.
after re-arranging price, loop over it and do something like
for( int i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
oldIndexOfMyValue = pricesUnordered.indexOf(value);

 newQuantity.push(Quantity[oldIndexOfMyValue]);
}

Comment: Johnny Mopp, technically I am, but I've never worked with structs or Tuples - I'll look into those later today, thanks.

Comment: FrenchMajesty, your logic is interesting - I'll definitely take a closer look at it when I get home from work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two seperate arrays that are related, wich is not a good thing. Make a Struct, Class or Tupel containing both values. Optionally also a custom comparer. Make a array of that type.

Then it would be as simple as calling [Array.Sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx).

In caess where there is no single order (sometimes you want to sort by prices times quantity. Sometimes single item price), Array.Sort() has overrides that allow you to [specify the comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f.aspx) to be used.

You could also go for Linq, if you have experience with it. But getting both values into one type is a requirement. And the perfect time to learn that.

Comment: If I were to create another class for this, how would the code look? Would I just move those arrays into the constructor of the other class, or set them as properties? After that, what would I do from there?

Comment: The laziest way* to initialise a struct, class or tupel is via Object Initialisers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). Writing a custom constructor that takes both arguments can be helpfull. But it will only be nessesary if the values have a private setter or are in some other way readonly.
*Not judging. being lazy when writing code is a good trait for a programmer.